# List and Iterator ADTs

Tags: arrays, list, collections, runtime, big-o

Suppose we are maintaining a collection C of elements such that, each time we add a new element to the collection, we copy the contents of C into a new array list of just the right size. What is the running time of adding n elements to an initially empty collection C in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The 1st element is added. (1 operation).
- The 2nd element is added. Copy the 1st element and add the new one (2 operations).
- The 3rd element is added. Copy the 1st and 2nd elements and add the new one (3 operations)
- The *n*th element is added. Copy (*n-1*) elements and add the new one (*n* operations).

Therefore, for adding *n* elements we have a total of 1+2+3+...+*n* operations, [which is equal to](http://mathandmultimedia.com/2010/09/15/sum-first-n-positive-integers/)  (n)(n+1)/2 = (n^2+n)/2. In [Big O Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), one would say that adding elements into that collection is **O(n^2)**.